# Is this the correct way to sort rows which have the same insert datetime?

Tags: sql, mysql, database, jdbc

When I execute a query from my application (Java JDBC), it is returning the row with seq 83 first. But I want the row with seq 84.

```
seq   |   dtCreated         |
84    | 2009-09-14 16:16:23 |
83    | 2009-09-14 16:16:23 |
82    | 2009-09-14 16:15:01 |
```

Is this query correct ? I'm interpreting this to mean that if there are ties in dtCreated, sort using seq.

```
select * from mim order by dtCreated DESC, seq DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are inerpreting correct.

[An Example](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)

> You can sort on multiple columns, and
>   you can sort different columns in
>   different directions. For example, to
>   sort by type of animal in ascending
>   order, **then by birth date** within
>   animal type in descending order
>   (youngest animals first), use the
>   following query:

See the result from

```
SELECT name, species, birth FROM pet
ORDER BY species, birth DESC
```

provided in the example.

Comment: Do you have a citation that backs this up ?